# React Js code not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

I have just started ReactJs and I am facing problem in output of the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My first react file</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='react-container'></div>
    <script type= "text/babel">
        /*
        ReactDOM.render(React.createElement('ul', null ,
            React.createElement('li', null , 'item 1'),
            React.createElement('li', null , 'item 2'),
            React.createElement('li', null , 'item 3')), 
            document.getElementById('react-container'));
        */
        ReactDOM.render(
            <ul>
                <li> item 1 </li>
                <li> item 2 </li>
                <li> item 3 </li>
            </ul>,
            document.getElementById('react-container'));
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The above code is not producing the expected output in the browser and in the console , I am getting the following error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined**

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: This sort of thing is often caused because you are using the wrong version of babel. Try a few different versions and see if the issue persists.

Comment: It was due to wrong version of babel. It should be less than 6.